# Wrong scroll on collapsing toolbar when i click options menu

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-optionsmenu

I created a profile page with coordinator layout as root element and collapsing toolbar and it's inner image view as a profile picture. The first view of the app only shows information and everything is okay till now!even options menu works great when collapsing toolbar is fully collapsed or expanded.but the problem appear when collapsing toolbar is a little collapsed or a little expanded! some strange things happened which you can see in screenshots!

When the options menu clicked some views turn visible and some turn went and the options menu itself replaces with another menu item which will cancel recent changes in views. Both items of options menu have above problem!

[image: before options menu clicked]

[image: after options menu clicked]

[image: after options menu clicked]

myprofile.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mp_coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="@color/semi_white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyProfile">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/mp_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/mp_collapsing"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/user_default"
            android:id="@+id/mp_iv_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mp_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ToolbarsTv"
            android:id="@+id/mp_tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>
```

on options item selected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        case R.id.mp_options_menu_edit:
            mp_btn_save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            item_edit.setVisible(false);
            item_cancel.setVisible(true);

            onEdit();
            break;
        case R.id.mp_options_menu_cancel:
            mp_btn_save.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            item_edit.setVisible(true);
            item_cancel.setVisible(false);
            onCancelEdit();

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was using two things in one layout,one was coordinator layout attribute `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` and other was a view attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"`